# Modifying a variable more than once in a statement and order of evaluation of function arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined-behavior

How do we reason about these JavaScript statements and explain their output?

1. `i = 1; i = i++; console.log(i);           // Outputs 1 in Firefox`
2. `i = 1; x = i++ + i++; console.log(i, x);  // Outputs 3 3 in Firefox`
3. `i = 1; console.log(i, i++);               // Outputs 1 1 in Firefox`

In C, the equivalent statements for (1) and (2) would be said to invoke undefined behavior because we are modifying the value of `i` more than once between two sequence points. In C, the equivalent statement for (3) would be said to invoke undefined behavior because the order of evaluation of function arguments is undefined. What are the rules in JavaScript?

Comment: What is the problem. A ; is a statement separator, so i gets incremented. There is also an operator precedence order. The only problem would be that some muppet would have written bad code. :-) In 2) x = 1 + 2 = 3;

Answer (score 2):

As per the [ECMA 5.1 Specification of Postfix Increment Operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.3.1),

> 1. Let `lhs` be the result of evaluating `LeftHandSideExpression`.
> 2. Let `oldValue` be `ToNumber(GetValue(lhs))`.
> 3. Let `newValue` be the result of adding the value 1 to `oldValue`, using the same rules as for the + operator (see 11.6.3).
> 4. Call `PutValue(lhs, newValue)`.
> 5. Return `oldValue`.

As per the rules, lets evaluate the expressions

#### `i = i++`

The value will be incremented and set in `i`. as per step 4 and 5. Then the `oldValue` 1 itself is returned and you are storing it again in `i`. That is why you are getting 1.

#### `x = i++ + i++`

The same logic. `i++` evaluates to `1` and `i` is set to 2. Now, the next `i++` is evaluated which evaluates to 2 and the value of `i` is set to 3. So the sum of 1 and 2 is assigned to `x`. That is why it prints `3 3`

#### `console.log(i, i++)`

Again, the same logic. `i` is 1 and `i++` evaluates to `1`, but the value is set to `2` only. That is why it prints `1 1`